# How to turn off screenshot sending from MacBook to iPhone?

Tags: iphone

When I do a screenshot on my MacBook, I see also this screenshot on my iPhone.
How I can disable sending screenshot action from my MacBook to my iPhone?

Comment: Does the screenshot show up in Photos.app? Sounds like the picture is going into Photos.app, and then syncing via iCloud.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which key shortcut do you use to take the screenshot? You may be saving the screenshot to the clipboard, and if Continuity is enabled, the clipboard is made available to your iPhone. See https://support.apple.com/HT201361 for more information on screenshots and https://support.apple.com/HT209460 for more information on Continuity and Universal Clipboard.